# Incorrect syntax near '='

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I correrct this Error? Error in this line: `readK.Fill(dt1);`.Thank you!

```
private void comboBox5_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox6.SelectedValueChanged -= comboBox6_SelectedValueChanged;
    DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
    BindingSource bd = new BindingSource();
    conn.Open();
    bd.DataSource = dt1;
    SqlCommand selK = new SqlCommand("Select * from Kafedra where id_fcultet=" + comboBox5.SelectedValue, conn);
    SqlDataAdapter readK = new SqlDataAdapter(selK);
    readK.Fill(dt1);
    comboBox6.DataSource = bd;
    comboBox6.DisplayMember = "name";
    comboBox6.SelectedIndex = -1;
    comboBox6.ValueMember = "id_kafedra";
    textBox2.Text = i + comboBox5.SelectedValue;
    conn.Close();
    comboBox6.SelectedValueChanged += comboBox6_SelectedValueChanged;
}
```

Comment: Well, you should start by parameterizing your SQL. Currently you're wide open for a SQL injection attack. Once you've done that (see `SqlDbCommand.Parameters`) you may well find that the problem is fixed already...

Comment: What is the value of _comboBox5.SelectedValue_ ?

Comment: there in comboBox5.SelectedValue = id_facultet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to fix this issue is to use sql-parameters which will also fix possible sql injection:

```
SqlCommand selK = new SqlCommand("Select * from Kafedra where id_facultet=@id_facultet, conn);
sqlK.Parameters.Add("@id_facultet", SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(comboBox5.SelectedValue.ToString());
```

If this code causes a `FormatException` `comboBox5.SelectedValue` is not an integer. If it's an integer in the first place(use the debugger) you could also use a cast: `... .Value = (int)comboBox5.SelectedValue;`

Answer (score 1):

String concatenation approach for building queries will opens a wide door for SQL Injection, So i strongly recommend you to use parameterized queries to avoid SQL Injection. Here is a example for doing the same:

```
 SqlCommand selK = new SqlCommand("Select * from Kafedra where id_facultet=@someID", conn);
 selK.Parameters.Add("@someID",SqlDbType.Varchar).value= comboBox5.SelectedValue;
```

You can choose the [`SqlDbType.Varchar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype(v=vs.110).aspx) as per the type of that specific field in the Table.

Comment: Please don't start an answer with "Your command should be like the following" when it certainly *shouldn't* be constructed that way at all. Parameterized SQL really is the only way to go here; I would strongly recommend removing the string concatenation approach entirely.

Comment: @JonSkeet: thanks for your valuable advise, that helps me to improve my answer.